# publish video facebook wall graph api

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have developed an application for facebook. I want to post a video on the users wall using the graph API. What can I do to publish video on facebook wall?

Comment: You should search through documentation
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/video.upload/

Answer (score 3):

Recently i have to do the same thing and to do it is very simple.

The parameters you must use are:

- source = urlencode ( url/to/swf )
- link = url/to/web
- picture = url/to/picture

And no more, so if you use the graph api you the url will be like:

https://graph.facebook.com/userID/feed?access_token=&source=urlencode
(url/to/swf)&picture=url/to/picture&link=url/to/web

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2011, Facebook has added the ability to upload videos through the new graph API:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/